# what are the step need to be followed inorder to retrain any pretrained neural network model?

Tags: neural-network, nlp, cnn, rnn

what are the step need to be followed inorder to retrain any pretrained neural network model ? ([How to load the pre-trained BERT model from local/colab directory?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/64323/how-to-load-the-pre-trained-bert-model-from-local-colab-directory/64513?noredirect=1#comment69886_64513) ) I tried to re train few pretrained neural network models . After retraining i get 3 CKPT files but im stuck on how i should proceed further after getting the 3 CKPT file . How to load the model buy pointing to these CKTP files ?